# Why base keyword can't be used in static methods?

Tags: c#

Why we can't use base keyword to use base class methods in static methods?

Both are available at compile time.

```
class A
{ 
    public virtual void Func(int a=4){
        Console.WriteLine(" A Class: "+a);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new void Func(int a = 12)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" B Class: "+ a);
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public static void Func()
    {
        base.Func();  // why not ????
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B ob = new C();
        ob.Func();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, `static` methods can only access other `static` members within their class.

Answer (score 16):

Because base keyword is referring to the base class of the current class **instance**.  But you do not have a current instance in static methods - they are static not instance.

You will be able to call `B.Func()`  if you made the `Func()` method static in class B.

Answer (score 1):

The [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) states in section **10.6.4 Override methods** (emphasis mine):

> A compile-time error occurs unless all of the following are true for an override declaration:
>
> ...
>
> - The overridden base method is a virtual, abstract, or override method. In other words, **the overridden base method cannot be static or non-virtual.**

Theoretically, it might be possible to look at the base class of the referenced type. After all, the inheritance relationship between classes is defined on the type, not the instance. For example, if I have `class A: B`, when presented with `A.Foo()`, the compiler could look for a `static virtual` method in B called `Foo` after looking in class `A` or for `base` in `A.Foo()` to return a list of static methods in `B`. However, I suspect this is a compiler optimization and language simplification to avoid having to handle references to a list of static methods only and the confusion it would cause.